# Managing dependencies with a simple Façade architecture pattern in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, architecture, dependencies, projects-and-solutions, layer

As a learning exercise on software architecture (and also on Visual Studio), I decided to create a set of four minimal WPF/C# applications (solutions) with a single purpose: read some circle parameters from file when a button is pressed, and display the result on the GUI:

1. One application reads from .txt file and displays the parameters in a textbox;
2. One application reads from .xml file and displays the circle in a canvas;
3. One application reads from .txt and displays the circle;
4. One application reads from .xml and displays the text parameters;

That is, I have one Domain project containing a Circle class, two DataAccess projects (one for xml and other for txt), and two presentation projects (one for geometry drawing, and other for displaying text). Each of the four solutions refers to a combination of these reusable, modularized projects.

Also, I'd like to use the FAÇADE design pattern, so that the Presentations "see" the façade but not data-access or domain. The Façade sees the Domain and the DataAccess, and each DataAccess just do their business blindly.

THE PROBLEMS are these:

- I needed two Façades, because I have to create a namespace dependency to one of the two DataAccess layers in order to use the DataAccess namespace inside the Façade project. So one Façade depends on the XmlBackend, and other depends on TxtBackend;
- Each Presentation depends on the Façade so that the namespaces are available, but SINCE I HAVE TWO FAÇADES, each Presentation project would end up depending on two different Façade projects, which is a Bad Thing;

I tried to create a single Façade project, so that each Presentation would refer to it, but then this Façade would depend on two different DataAccess backends. Then in a solution, I could not have only one DataAccess backend project, because the Façade project would depend on two different ones.

So the question is: How I could resolve this so that I can have four solutions, each solution having only the necessary projects (the domain, the façade, one presentation and one data backend), the layering architecture not being violated, and each project not needing to know too much about the others?

Update: the [Msdn Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says the folling, which I think might be a hint: "[solution explorer allows you to] add items that are useful to multiple projects in the solution or to the solution without referencing the item in each project."

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full decoupling and absolutely need the Façade to be reusable independently from the two DataAccess modules, you could have the Façade layer declare an `IDataAccess` interface that classes in both DataAccess projects would implement.

A third party module (one of the GUI's ?) would then inject the correct DataAccess concrete implementation into the Façade as needed at runtime.

As a side note, part of your problem comes from the fact that in this architecture, 1 project pretty much == 1 class, so *object* tight coupling and *project* tight coupling concerns are mixed up.

However, you should note that object tight coupling leads to fragility, poor maintainability and testability while project coupling only affects reusability. In other words, you *could* live with Façade referencing both DataAccess projects, it would only mean that you can't reuse Façade in another context/architecture without the DataAccess projects somewhere at hand.

Comment: Thanks! You have got things very right. I liked the dependency injection consideration, I've read a lot about it. Also, I have read about project configuration and metadata in Visual Studio, but didn't have time to dive into this yet. It would be nice to keep this "between project" dependencies at the solution level, instead of inside each project. I'll wait a bit more, and probably come back to accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I have quickly felt the need for more objects inside each project, and more projects/layers for further separation of concerns.

Comment: The reason why dependencies are defined at project level rather than solution level is to keep projects as standalone units that can be reused across multiple solutions. Also note that while some degree of project decoupling and dependency injection is nice, some dependencies between projects (in your example, GUI => Façade) are only natural and shouldn't be avoided.

Comment: Nice. Just one last consideration: you say inter-project dependencies shouldn't be at solution level, so that projects can be reused in multiple solutions. But if I take one project which in one solution depends on project Xa, how could I use it in another solution where it depends in project Xb... There seems to be some coupling here. BUT, sometimes I notice the references appear "grayed out" or "warned" (unavailable) in the project references folder, and even so, it seems, the solution builds fine. I appreciate your interest!

Comment: As far as I know, you can't have project X depend on project Xa in one solution and Xb in another. If you open the .csproj file in plain text, you'll see that project references are defined using a relative path to the referenced .csproj but also mention its Guid. I guess when Visual Studio fails to find the csproj file from the path, it displays a warning but still manages to lay its hands on it based on the Guid.